# Put BLOB from DataBase to Directory

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I have a PDF file saved into a Table in BLOB TypeFile, but i can't figures how to put this file into a directory.

In the past i create an interface plain text into this directory (i have some experience in this):

```
FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('directoryName', 'fileName', 'W');

FOR REC IN (    SELECT LPAD(t1.var1, 18, 0)                ||
                       LPAD(t1.var2, 18, 0)                ||
                       LPAD(t2.var1, 1, 0)                 ||
                       LPAD(REPLACE(t2.person_id, '-'), 9, 0) AS trace
                  FROM tbl1 t1,
                       tbl2 t2
                 WHERE a = b;
            )
LOOP
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (FILE, REC.trace);
END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (FILE);
```

But, now i have to drop a PDF into the same directory, help!

Comment: You can find something useful [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/export-blob-9i)

Comment: excelent!, this exactly was what i'm looking for!